# Problems with C rand()

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I just came across the rand() function. The book states that using rand() returns a random number from 0 to 32767. It also states that you can narrow the random numbers by using % (modulus operator) to do so.
Here is an example: the following expression puts a random number from 1 to 6 in the variable dice

```
dice = (rand() % 6) + 1;
```

I’m wondering  why you can’t use

```
dice = (rand() % 7);
```

Won’t it do the same thing?

Comment: Do the math: x / 6 + 1 is not the same as x / 7 !

Comment: Do you want a 0-6 range or a 1-6 range?

Comment: from  0 to 32767 -> from 0 to at least 32767.

Comment: *The book states that using rand() returns a random number from 0 to 32767.*  Your book is wrong, there.  (I wonder how many other false facts it's teaching you?)  On a 32-bit machine it typically returns numbers over a much larger range.  There's a constant, `RAND_MAX`, which tells you the range of `rand()` on your system.

Comment: The value of `RAND_MAX` (the maximum value returned by `rand()`) does not have to be 32767.  It can’t be smaller, but it is often much larger.

Comment: The result of the first expression will always be >= 1.  That is not true for the 2nd expression which can return 0.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a math question than a C question. The answer lies in modulo arithmetic. Any number `x modulo n` equals 0 if `n` divides `x` evenly. *In fact, the modulo operator returns the remainder of integer division.* Therefore the range is from `0` to `n - 1`. So if you want a random number 1-6 you need to perform `(rand() % 6) + 1`, since `rand() % 6` gives you something in the range of 0-5. Simply doing `rand() % 7` gives you the range 0-6, increasing the upper bound, not the lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

`rand() % 6` is a number in the interval 0-5.
If you add one to any number in that interval, you get a number in the interval 1-6.

On the other hand, `rand() % 7` is a number in the interval 0-6.